# ebean limit resultset using setMaxRows

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm creating a Query with parameters from a searchform using ebean in play! framework 2.0.4. Depending on the given paramters the result can have up to one million rows. So I'm limiting the result using setMaxRows(100). At the end I have a list of 100 entries, but the real statement requesting the data is missing the LIMIT keyword and all the data is stored in the memory...

```
Query<Process> query = Process.find.fetch("documents").fetch("documents.workflows").fetch("documents.workflows.state");
ExpressionList<Process> expression = query.where().between("documents.workflows.date", new java.sql.Date(edit_date.getTime()), new java.sql.Date(edit_to.getTime()));
procs = expression.setMaxRows(100).orderBy().desc("id").findList();
```

Java
Postgresql 9.1
ebean 2.7.3
play! framework 2.0.4

Can anyone tell me why ebean isn't using the LIMIT keyword in my case?

Comment: This is a 3 years old issue against a very old version of Ebean but ... I just wanted to say that in cases like this I'd encourage you to post to the Ebean google group.  Certainly a LIMIT clause would be here but with fetching @OneToMany's Ebean would also automatically break this into multiple sql statements etc.  Stackoverflow is not always the best forum to get the help you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't use LIMIT in the statement, I found identical situation yesterday.

My solution (which is acceptable for me) is creating custom query with [RawSql](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/RawSql.html) and/or [SqlQuery](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html) (both allows to create custom statement)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using ebean to build a bite more complicated nested search statement based on the parameters given in a search form. Without ebean it would be to messy. Is there a way to get the generated statement without executing it before? so i could add the limit by hand and then use rawsql?

Comment: Of course I don't want to enforce you, but I found exactly opposite conclusion: the more advanced queries needs manual creating for optimal usage (not always, but sometimes...). I'm regularly checking statements prepared by Ebean and often I'm replacing them with custom SQLs. Nota bene if you'll use a statement logging you can see (and copy) Ebean's statement and write a method which will do the same code with your changes. Most probably you'll also find some fields for optimization and improvements.